# convert gwiki (old GoogleCode wiki) to something new e.g. markdown

Tags: markdown

I'm struggling to find a a proper way to convert my old GoogleCode Wikis to GitHub Wiki.

I've tried `pandoc` and `txt2tags` so far with no success. Essentially, I can't find what format Google Code wikis used. I need something to properly convert to, e.g., `markdown`, things like:

```
= HEAD =

* Bullet

*Bold*

* *Bold text in a bullet*

~~strikeout~~

_italic_

`code`

[http://www.example.com A link]
```

I've tried my example above in https://pandoc.org/try for all possible input formats and the closest I got was:

`pandoc --from vimwiki --to gfm`

But it misses URLs and I don't like its bold solution with `<span id="Bold"></span>**Bold**` (it should be just `**Bold**`).

Using `txt2tags`, I got close too with:

`txt2tags -v -t md my_example.gwiki`

Yet, it **swaps** URL with **text** and **bold** renders as *italic*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know that isn't a standard markup language. It might have been specific to Google Code.

There is a very old¹ project called [`gcw2html`](https://yarnpkg.com/package/gcw2html) that claims to do what you want:

> A simple command-line utility to convert Google Code wiki markup to HTML using [wikiwm](http://code.google.com/p/wikiwym/) (sic), a JavaScript Google Code wiki library.

Its README even shows how to pipe its output into Pandoc and Ruby to generate Markdown (though Pandoc has changed a *lot* since 2011 and you might have to adjust):

```sh
gcw2html filename.wiki \
  | pandoc --from html --to markdown --no-wrap \
  | ruby -e 'puts STDIN.readlines.to_s.gsub(/\[([^\]]*)\]\(http:\/\/code\.google\.com\/p\/[^\/]*\/wiki\/([^\)]*)\)/,"[[\\1 | \\2]]")'
```

There is also an archived Python project called [`statwiki`](https://code.google.com/archive/p/statwiki/) that claims to generate HTML from Google Code wiki-formatted content. It was originally taken from MoinMoin and then

> Slightly modify the syntax to match Google's Code Wiki Syntax

From HTML, you should be able to generate Markdown using Pandoc as shown above, though `statwiki` may not read from `stdin` and print to `stdout`. Its [archived source code](https://code.google.com/archive/p/statwiki/source/default/source) is available for download.

---

¹One release, version 0.1.0, came out in August, 2011. There is a single contributor.

Comment: I didn't manage to get `gcw2html` to work, issues with `npm glob`. Second option with `statwiki` gave instersitng results, but I realised that I still need to work on the output, but I'd say it's an acceptable answer.